# @src pull out info as data:gif instead of direct image link

Tags: xpath

I am trying to scrape images from link but when I do so using src it gives the links as

> data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7

instead of

> https://www.ordervenue.com/images/thumbnails/170/170/detailed/44/$*12*(5).JPG?t=1462168530

my code is as follows:-

```
$url="https://www.ordervenue.com/rs-99-special-store.html";


$html = file_get_contents($url); //get the html returned from the following url

$mydoc = new DOMDocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); //disable libxml errors

if(empty($html)) die("EMPTY HTML");

    $mydoc->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_clear_errors(); //remove errors for yucky html

    $my_xpath = new DOMXPath($mydoc);
    $nodes = $my_xpath->query( '//div[@class="vs-grid vs-grid-table"]' );

    foreach( $nodes as $node )
        {
    $imglink=$my_xpath->query( 'div[1]/div/a/img//@src', $node )->item(0)->nodeValue ;  
    echo $imglink."<br>";
    }
}
```

how do get it to pull the image links correctly

Answer (score 0):

As it seems, the image is included in the source code of the html, in a base64 encoded format. To get the original image, you need to decode the string back to the binary data, therefore you can use [base64_decode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.base64-decode.php). So as given in the examples of the page you need to do something like:

```
//$encodedData is what $imglink is in your code
$encodedData = str_replace('data:image/gif;base64,','',$encodedData);
$decocedData = base64_decode($encodedData);

file_put_contents('/path/to/file/name.gif', $decocedData);
```

Than you can save the `$decocedData` at a place you wish as a `*.gif` file.

**UPDATE**

To answer the question:

> how to use this with my code above to get the links

In short: You can't. That is because the image data is included in the html, so there is no link to the image either. (One could say: The link is the data itself) You have the the image, if you need a link, you have to create it yourself, by uploading the image to any reachable webspace.

**UPDATE #2**

Please note that `file_put_content()` can handle Streams ([php Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.streamwrapper.php)). Even if this is beyond the scope of this question, with that you could implement the usage of a cloud- or  webservice, where you can »put the file contents« to. This way you would publish the image and get a link to it. But as I said, this is beyond the scope of this question and just an Idea how one could implement it…

Comment: how to use this with my code above to get the links